# How to make the Div fixed at a particular scroll location?

Tags: html, css

Like in Yahoo.com, when we scroll the page downwards its Search Box gets stuck to the top of the window on a particular scroll location? How to do that, Is it possible using css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a container div for the div that will be fixed. The div that you want to show always at the top will be inside this div like this:

```
<div id="fixedDivWrapper">
  </div id="scroll">
    This stays still!
  </div>
```

and your css:

```
position: fixed; /*This fixes it to the top of the div.*/
top: 20px; /*Margin at the top of the fixed div*/
```

Comment: But I need to make it fixed(or Stick) only when page is Scrolled Downwards...example: `http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/` in this site scroll the page downwards and see the right div.

Comment: Ah i didnt answer how they have done it. I will change my answer

Answer (score 1):

A neat CSS/JavaScript [solution](http://www.derekallard.com/blog/post/conditionally-sticky-sidebar).

Answer (score 0):

You should define

```
position: fixed;
top: 10px;
left: 20px;
```

this will hang div 10px from top and 20px from left and it will stuck there during page scroll.

Also you should add some other properties you want, - maybe display: block; and other parameters.

Comment: I want that DIV should be fixed only after reaching a certain scroll position. Like `right sidebar` in facebook

Comment: then, you need some javascript. you are not able to do it only with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
position: fixed;
```

However be aware this dosnt work in IE6 or iOS Safari < 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very basic demo that does exactly what you want. Using jQuery to simplify tasks but this is simple enough you could make it pure JS if you wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/uU8Wb/

What this does is simple;

1. It saves some variables I will need later & never changes in variables like the offset to the top initially.
2. Binds an event to the scroll event of the window, in the event we do a simple check to see if the current position from the top is more or less than the offset of the element we want scrolling with the window.
3. If the scrolltop is more and it lacks the class it should have at that moment we assign it, css does the rest, and the other way arround when the position from the top becomes less than the original offset of our element.

Simplicity is all the magic here, if we can do both tasks with CSS but need to choose between when each state is active we simply write a script that switches a class rather than relying on JS to do it all.